# How to modify text of Field using Popup

Tags: popup, field, playn

Here again with new question.I am using a Field like this:

```
    Field field = new Field(" Enter Your Text ");
    field.setEnabled(true);
    field.layer.setInteractive(true);
    field.setTextType(Keyboard.TextType.DEFAULT);
```

When i am clicking it, a popup is coming to enter its text.In Api doc it is written it is written we can modify its value by using:

```
Keyboard.getText(playn.core.Keyboard.TextType, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, playn.core.util.Callback)
```

So how can i use it as it Keyboard is an interface and getText(...) is not static.I want this popup to appear on a button click event.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this silly question.i got my answer.You can do the popup like this :

```
PlayN.keyboard().getText(textType, label, initialValue, callback);
```

Hope it will help someone. :)